# Laravel printing out in the blade the count of a unique element in the db

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a table with several different domains.  What I am trying to do is print out each unique domain and the number of times that domain appears in my db.  For example if I had the domain of test 4 times in my db it would print out

> test 4

I have it so I print out the unique values, but cannot figure out how to print out the number of times that value occurs in my table

Here is my controller code

```
public function updateExpirationDate()
{
    $users = User::select('domain')->distinct()->get();
   // dd($users);
    return view('admin.updatebulkexpirationdate', compact('users'));

}
```

Here is my blade code

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
        <tr id='{{ $user->domain }}'>
            <td>{{ $user->domain }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->domain->count()}}</td> //How Do I get the count of each domain
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the data:

```
$users = User::select('domain')->get();
```

Use the collection methods [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) and [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count):

```
{{ $user->where('domain', $user->domain)->count() }}
```

Note, that here you're working with loaded data and not executing additional queries.